# How to use validation to only accept certain integers in Python?

Tags: python, validation, integer, range, try-catch

I am asking a question about the problem of only accepting certain integers in Python. This is *different* from excepting numbers between a range such as 8 > and <32.

Instead, I want a user input to not except certain integers such as 3, 4 or 2. If these integers are inputted, they will be not be accepted and the will be input run again.

I have tried using try and except and looping through the input as list in order to identify any unwanted integers. I have expected the to match these up to the variables containing the integers to check/validate but I do not truly understand how to do this.

Comment: Put them in a list, then use `if user_input not in that_list:`

Comment: Please show what you tried. If you use `try/except` you need something that raises an exception if the input is in the list of restrictions.

Comment: okay thank you, I think that will help.